# Blazor WASM project forces to authenticate every time the project is started

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM and a ASP.NET Core Web API setup to work with Azure Active Directory for Authentication (setup according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-7.0) with [additional scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0) since in my case the two are separate projects).

Authentication on the WASM project as well as API via accessed toke works quite fine, however the login procedure has to be done every time the projects are started (with MFA this becomse quite a hassle).

To avoid this I have added the following line to `Program.cs` of the WASM project:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    // MSAL setup config with AAD here

    if(builder.HostEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
});
```

Cool, now I don't need to login everytime anymore, however unfortunately with this the Authorization on the API will fail:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
> Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
> DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.

Is it possible to solve this issue? Will users in production be forced to login every time they access the site as well? Shouldn't a token be valid for a certain amount of time?

**Edit**
Some additional Info. The `HttpClient` is configured with a `CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler` as follows:

*Program.cs*

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MyAPI", client =>
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7124"))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

*CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler.cs*

```
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigation)
        : base(provider, navigation)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:7124" },
            scopes: new[] { "api://<<some id>>/API.Access" });
    }
}
```

Comment: pls allow me to post my code snippet below to show you better. what i mean is that, your code worked for me, so i think we'd better to check the access token for calling the api and try to narrow down the issue. what I shared below is how I generate the access token and call api.

Answer (score 1):

I have a test in my side with your configuration `options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";` which makes me no need to sign in again, and I tried to call the web api which is protected by Azure AD and it worked as well. But I don't have MFA in my App.

Here's my code about calling API, I'm afraid you can check if the token generated correctly when the issue happened.

```
@page "/profile"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
@attribute [Authorize]
@inherits UserProfileBase
@inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider

<h3>User Profile</h3>
<button @onclick="call">
    call api
</button>
<div>@result</div>


@code {

    private string result = "no data now";

    private async Task call()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        http.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7018/WeatherForecast");

        var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(
            new AccessTokenRequestOptions
                {
                    Scopes = new[] { "api://aad_Client_id/Tiny.Read" }
                });

        if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
        {
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization",
                $"Bearer {token.Value}");
            result = await http.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:7018/WeatherForecast");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah... my implementation is a bit different, as I have a custom authorization message handler, which collects the token for each call. I'll add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: thank you for your repply sir, and in your new code, I can see a method `ConfigureHandler` which set the scope and request url for calling the api, but it didn't contain a part for obtaining the token...

Comment: Yes, accessing the token is actually done in the base class `AuthorizationMessageHandler`, [which is a provided  .NET class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.authorizationmessagehandler?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: thank you, and I noticed that you had `IAccessTokenProvider provider` when construct `CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler`, could you please manually generate an access token to check if it could generate successfully and whether the token contained the correct scope?